# Add new column to existing type

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

I have a type:

```
create or replace type employee FORCE as object (
   id VARCHAR2(8),
   code NUMBER(11) )
```

I'm trying to add another column to the type, so it will be as follows:

```
create or replace type employee FORCE as object (
   id VARCHAR2(8),
   code NUMBER(11),
   date NUMBER(8) )
```

I'm getting an error though:

```
ORA-22866: cannot replace a type with table dependents
22866. 00000 -  "default character set is of varying width"
*Cause:    A character `LOB` was defined but the default character
           set is not fixed width.
*Action:   Ensure that the character set is of fixed width before defining
           character `LOBs`.
```

How can I add another column to this type?

Is there any way to add the new column to the type instead of dropping all tables that use this type. 
Is there anything which can be Enabled/disabled to complete this action.... 
because dropping those tables is not possibe in my scenario...

Comment: Hi `date` is a _really_ bad name for a column as it's a reserved words and needs to be quoted. Consider changing the name to something like `employment_date` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have already used type "employee" in a table. You need to first drop all tables that use this type and then change it. You should also change the "date" field cause its a keyword.

Comment: No. Do not drop existing data. Use `alter type add attribute` instead.

Comment: Alter type employee add date NUMBER(8);
throws the following error



06545. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: compilation error - compilation aborted"
*Cause:    A pl/sql compilation error occurred and the compilation was
           aborted completely without the compilation unit being written
           out to the backing store.  Unlike ora-06541, the user will always
           see this error along with the accompaning PLS-nnnnn error messages.
*Action:   See accompanying PLS-nnnnn error messages.

Comment: Is there any way to add the new column to the type instead of dropping all tables that use this type. Is there anything which can be Enabled/disabled to complete this action.... because dropping those tables is not possibe in my scenario...

Comment: And what about `Alter type employee add attribute employment_date DATE;` NOTE: attribute is reseved word. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4002.htm